# New to REST API

Tags: php, rest, authorization

basically I have been assigned to build a REST request application in PHP, using a 3rd party REST API. Doing POSTs, GETs etc seems simple, however they have something called an Authorization header which uses a Digest token. How do I pass this via a get?

EG:

```
$url = "http:/domain/core.xml";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
echo $response;
```

Returns : Digest auth headers not found

In FireFoxes POSTER i would simply add the header "Authorization" with the value "Digest 0:codehere" and it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file-get-contents)

```
string file_get_contents ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context [, int $offset = -1 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )
```

The third argument `$context` allows you to add a context create by [stream_context_create()](http://php.net/stream-context-create). See [HTTP context options](http://php.net/context.http). There you can find an option `header`, that allows you to set headers to be used by the request you send, in your case the `Authorization`-header

Answer (score 5):

You can use curl for Rest calls. For your help these are the help link:
[auth token using curl](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wldatadev/thread/aaee5671-7695-40ac-9d0d-1a36ad98cc29)

[What is Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Comment: Thanks, may be using curl so this will help

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$url ="http://example.com/target.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'username:password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

In server side (target.php) we can access the username and password as follows.

```
$USERNAME = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$PASSWORD = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
```

In certain cases the $_SERVER VARIABLES NOT AVAILABLE TO YOUR LOCAL SERVER. SO PLEASE PUT
THE FOLLOWING CODE IN YOUR HTACCESS. THE HTTP AUTHORIZATION MODULE WILL WORK IN PHP. THE REASON IS THAT WE HAVE TO INSTALL THIS AS SEPARATE MODULE

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```